# Amazon Connect + Amazon S3 and possibility of making a call to a telephone number

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, phone-call, amazon-connect

I am doing my Uni assignment. What I need to do is create a bot or some program that would be able to use audio files from Amazon S3 database, call into specific phone number and then play the audio file which is a recording. I have developed an app that records a message sends it into bucket on Amazon S3.

What I understand so far, using Amazon Connect I can make a call and play a prompt that is uploaded directly from my drive. Is there a possibility to create a prompt from files stored in an Amazon S3 bucket directly? Maybe using ARN number or url? And is there any materials that You can send me to for guidance in using Amazon Connect for creating phone call? And how to trigger this call?
Edit:

I want to use Connect to play this recording to the recipient of this call

Comment: Whats your objective - is it simply to place a phone call with a specific message?

Comment: Sorry, I should specify that, I want to use Connect to play this recording of the recipient of this call

Comment: This answer is a bit too broad for SO. You would have to go to builfaast or something similar for this.

https://buildfaast.com/